# Hibernate Выборка данных

Tags: spring, hibernate

В базе данных есть 2 таблицы:

```
|------Отдел-----|                  
| ИД Отдела      |  
| Наименование   |     
| ....           |              
|----------------|               

|----Сотрудник---|                  
| ИД Сотрудника  |  
| ФИО            |     
| ИД Отдела (FK) |     
| ....           |              
|----------------|
```

Проблема в том, как мне выбрать средствами Hibernate все отделы и количество сотрудников по каждому отделу?
Мой прежний вариант выбирал все отделы и всех сотрудников по отделам, но при этом тянул все данные по сотрудникам, что не совсем оптимально, т.к. нужно их количество. Я конечно могу посчитать количество при помощи `.size()`. Но хотелось бы не нагружать Hibernate лишней работой и не заставлять его тащить всю информацию по сотрудникам.

Подскажите как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: Если у Вы беспокоитесь о производительности, то лучше вообще никак не вычислять количество при каждом чтении из БД. Обычно, эффективнее его вычислять только при изменении данных, и сохранять в отдельном поле. Тогда при чтении будет простая, плоская выборка данных с минимальной нагрузкой. В большинстве Систем количество операций записи данных гораздо ниже, чем количество операций чтения тех же данных, за счёт этого соотношения и получается выигрыш при использовании предлагаемого мной варианта. Значение поля счётчика в департаменте можно пересчитывать в триггере на таблице сотрудников

Comment: @bobzer Спасибо, за совет!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете попробовать использовать `org.hibernate.annotations.Formula`:

```
@Formula("(select count(e.id) from Employee e where e.department.id = id)")
private int employeesCount;
```

В коде, отдел:

```
@Entity
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<Employee>();

    @Formula("(select count(e.id) from Employee e where e.department.id = id)")
    private int employeesCount;

    //gets and sets
}
```

Сотрудник:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Department department;
    private String firstName;

    //gets and sets
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! В моем случае запрос стал выполняться на ~15-20% быстрее.